# How to change the color of a UITableViewCell to blue when is selected

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I use a UITableView in my application and the requirement is when I press one cell of my UITableView to go to the next view the color of that particular cell should be changed to blue.

How can I do this following is my code.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"dealsCC";
    dealsCC *cell = (dealsCC *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    [cell selectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
}
```

Please tell me,

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set the selectionStyle.

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
```

Answer (score 0):

in the didselectrowAtIndexPath you have to write this code

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [table cellforRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
```

Comment: I have tried this out but it is not working is there any other method?

Comment: write the below code in the cellforRowAtIndexPath                       [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];

Comment: static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"dealsCC";
 dealsCC *cell = (dealsCC *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row animated:YES];
    [cell selectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];

Comment: remove the line of [tableview deselectrowAtindexpath:indexPath.row animated:YES];//this is to remove the selection of a tableviewcell

Comment: clean the targets and run it.

Comment: still i m not getting the result.

Comment: is that statement executing?check whether the line is executing or not?

Comment: I want to clarify that on the line [cell selectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];

Comment: warning msg like "dealsCC may not respond to -selectionStyle" exists.

Comment: what is dealsCC is it inherited the uitbleviewCell or not?

Comment: yes in my app dealsCC.xib is file used to put as a cell in tableview

Answer (score 0):

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCellId";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIView *v = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        **cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;**
    }
    // Set up the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = @"foo";
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeap.
I do it like this

```
    UIView *bgColorSelected = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [bgColorSelected setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:180.0f/255.0f green:36.0f/255.0f blue:21.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorSelected;
    [bgColorSelected release];
    cell.backgroundColor = [ UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
}
```